# React View is not updated with redux

Tags: reactjs, view, redux, jsx

The react view is not updated (the render is never called) but the reducer was invoked.

I have the following:

1). the react view: I a field in the root state to determent if I need to show "TodoList" or "HousingInfo"

```jsx
export default class RightPane extends React.Component{
static contextTypes = {
    store: React.PropTypes.object
  }

render(){
    let store = this.context.store;
    let curPage = store.getState()["mainRightPanePage"].currentPage;
    return (
         <div>
             {(store.getState()["mainRightPanePage"].currentPage==="TodoList") && <TodoList/>}
             {(store.getState()["mainRightPanePage"].currentPage==="HousingInfo") && <HousingInfo/>}
         </div>
    )
}
```

}

2). the action dispatching in another component

```jsx
 export default class LeftPane extends React.Component{
    static contextTypes = {
         store: React.PropTypes.object
      }
    handleink(pageId, e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let store = this.context.store;
        store.dispatch({'type':'switchPage', 'pageId':pageId});
    ...
}
```

3). the reducer: the following reducer was invoked

```jsx
 const mainRightPanePage = (state = {'currentPage':'TodoList'}, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
     case 'switchPage':
       return Object.assign({}, state, {
          currentPage: action.pageId
      })
  default:
    return state
  }
}

 export default mainRightPanePage
```

What did I miss?

thanks

Comment: where did you use `store.subscribe()`? or you can use `react-redux` to connect the store data to components

Answer (score 4):

In your example the `RightPane` component is not aware that Redux state was updated because you haven't subscribed to Redux state changes. You can subscribe to Redux store directly using [subscribe](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#subscribe) method or you can connect your components to Redux store using [connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) method from `React-Redux` (recommended):

```jsx
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
...

class RightPane extends React.Component{
    ...
    render(){
        let currentPage = this.props.currentPage;
        return (
             <div>
                 {(currentPage === "TodoList") && <TodoList/>}
                 {(currentPage === "HousingInfo") && <HousingInfo/>}
             </div>
        )
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        currentPage: state.mainRightPanePage.currentPage
    }
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(RightPane);
```